# seeking thrust openmp paradigms

Tags: openmp, thrust, tbb

When using the OpenMP or TBB backends for Thrust, it would seem that host and device memory are the same.  That would affect what is good programming style, i.e., never bother to copy host data to the device.  So far, so good, this one was obvious.

I'm looking for any other advice about how to write efficient programs with the OpenMP or TBB backends.  Thanks.

Yes, I did a search, but found nothing.

Comment: Could you please narrow your question? It is definitely too broad.

Comment: My process of trying to use Thrust goes as follows:   I try something that is obvious to me.  Sometimes it works.  Other times it fails to compile or runs surprisingly slowly.   An example of the first is trying to access a component of an element of a vector of non-POD type.   An example of the second is sorting a vector of non-POD type.    Researching these case-by-case after the fact is very slow and sometimes fails.    For C++, there is an extensive list of issues, which I can proactively read to see what to avoid.   I'm seeking such a thing for Thrust.  However maybe this is too broad.